# Give initial value to the Sqlite when onCreate

Tags: android, sqlite

I give initial value to the Sqlite when onCreate.
But the Android Monitor show the error message below.

Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)
Caused By : The database file is locked.
(database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
private SQLiteDatabase DefaultWritableDatabase = null;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "arrived.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    final SQLiteDatabase db;
    if (DefaultWritableDatabase != null) {
        db = DefaultWritableDatabase;
    } else {
        db = super.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return db;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.DefaultWritableDatabase = db;
    // Create table
    String Create_Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  arrivedservice ("
            + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "Lat TEXT ,"
            + "Lon TEXT , "
            + "LeaveTime INTEGER "
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(Create_Query);

    //Give initial value to the Sqlite when onCreate
    String LeaveTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String Insert_Query = "INSERT INTO arrivedservice (_id,Lat,Lon,LeaveTime) VALUES ('1','240.22652','151.523978'," + LeaveTime + ")";
    db.execSQL(Insert_Query);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this line before execute insert query

```
db.getWritableDatabase();// add this line
String LeaveTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
String Insert_Query = "INSERT INTO arrivedservice (_id,Lat,Lon,LeaveTime) VALUES ('1','240.22652','151.523978'," + LeaveTime + ")";
db.execSQL(Insert_Query);
db.close();
```

Comment: That would result in "called recursively" exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` that was passed to `onCreate()` as an argument. You didn't open it, and you don't own it.